# Copy data from one table to another table using cursors in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

i have two tables .One full of data and the second is empty
i wan't to copy the first one into the second but using cursor in sql server
please help!

Comment: Why would you need to use cursors? Just use an Insert with SELECT * from the table which has values.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RyanWilson i know that query but i want it with cursor

Comment: @Hasnah May I ask why you want to use Cursors as it produces more overhead and are relatively slower.

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: isn't a homework,i want to know how ...if u can help i'll be pleased

Comment: See documentation... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
```

Comment: this query without cursor i wanna use cursor!

Comment: Why would you want to use a cursor?  Really bad idea.

Comment: I know! but it's challenge hahahaha!